# Нужно сравнить два ключа в массиве и вывести где совпало php

Tags: php, массивы

Допустим есть массив

```
$presidents = [
        [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Теодор Рузвельт',
        'year_leader' => '14.09.1901',
        'year_left' => '04.03.1909',
        'party' => 'Республиканец',
        'leader_days' => 2728,
        'vice_president' => 'Чарльз Фэрбенкс',
        ],
        [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Уильям Тафт',
        'year_leader' => '04.03.1909',
        'year_left' => '04.03.1913',
        'party' => 'Республиканец',
        'leader_days' => 1461,
        'vice_president' => 'Джеймс Шерман',
        ],];
```

мне нужно узнать вообще по заданию кто из вице-президентов был президентом(это ключ name и vice_president). Я через foreach прогоняю массив и сравниваю

```
$names = array_column($presidents, 'name');
    $vice = array_column($presidents, 'vice_president');
   $resp_visces = $dem_visec= $pres_vice =[]; // записываем в три переменные пустой массив
    foreach($presidents as $key => $val){
        $val['party'];
        if($val['party'] === 'Республиканец'){
            $resp_visces[]=$val['vice_president'];         
        }
        else{
            $dem_visec[]=$val['vice_president'];
        }
        if($vice == $names){
            $pres_vice[] = $val['vice_president'];
        }
    }
print_r($pres_vice);
```

ну и вывожу естественно, только вот мне он выводит пустой массив

```
Array (
)
```

Я вроде же всё правильно делаю, что не так то?
Допустим кто-то там придерётся из вас к переменной $val, то вот я делал другим циклом и всё равно тоже самое

```
foreach($presidents as $key1 => $value){
        $value['vice_president'];
        if($value['vice_president'] == $names){
            $pres_vice[] = $value['vice_president'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так у вас в массиве нигде не совпадает имя президента и вице-президента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с поиском пересечения массивов на мой взгляд более правильное. Но, если Вам по каким-то причинам все же хочется поиграться с перебиранием массивов в циклах, то вот Вам решение на них :)

```php
<?php
$presidents = [
        [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Джеймс Шерман',
        'year_leader' => '14.09.1901',
        'year_left' => '04.03.1909',
        'party' => 'Республиканец',
        'leader_days' => 2728,
        'vice_president' => 'Чарльз Фэрбенкс',
        ],
        [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Уильям Тафт',
        'year_leader' => '04.03.1909',
        'year_left' => '04.03.1913',
        'party' => 'Республиканец',
        'leader_days' => 1461,
        'vice_president' => 'Джеймс Шерман',
        ]
];

function isVpWasP( $vpName, $pArray ) {
    $result = false;
    foreach( $pArray as $p ) {
        if ( $vpName == $p['name'] ) {
            $result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

foreach( $presidents as $p ) {
    if ( isVpWasP( $p['vice_president'], $presidents ) ) {
        echo $p['vice_president']." был президентом\n";
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Джеймс Шерман был президентом
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему так сильно парится? Вы можете просто исрользовать фунскию `array_intersect`
Как-то так

```
$presidents = [
        [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Джеймс Шерман',
        'year_leader' => '14.09.1901',
        'year_left' => '04.03.1909',
        'party' => 'Республиканец',
        'leader_days' => 2728,
        'vice_president' => 'Чарльз Фэрбенкс',
        ],
        [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Уильям Тафт',
        'year_leader' => '04.03.1909',
        'year_left' => '04.03.1913',
        'party' => 'Республиканец',
        'leader_days' => 1461,
        'vice_president' => 'Джеймс Шерман',
        ]];

$president = array_column($presidents, 'name');
$vice_president = array_column($presidents, 'vice_president');

$result_array = array_intersect($president, $vice_president);
print_r($result_array);
```

Ответ :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Джеймс Шерман
)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я просто не знал про эту функцию. Я видел что-то похожее только там было array_intersect_key и он тоже не работал, а этот сработал